# asp mvc form input is non en-US culture having trouble with numeric values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP.net MVC globalized application

I would like to know the best way to handle updates when the input has numeric values but they are entered using the users culture not default of server (en-US); I am guessing there is something built in to asp MVC to handle this situation but I came up short on Google searching.

an example: the logged on user has the culture 'fr-FR', so numbers are displayed and entered using comma instead of period for decimal 
example 5.55 (en-US) vs 5,55 (fr-FR)

Given two input fields that accept numeric values

- Hours_1: 1,11
- Hours_2: 2,22

and an update action that captures these values

```
public ActionResult Update(string Hours_1, double? Hours_2) 
{ 
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Hours_1); // 1,11 
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Hours_2); // null 

    return null; 
}
```

by the time the update action executes the current thread has already been set to 'fr-FR' as well. A couple of options that come to mind - massage the data via javascript before form submission (not ideal), update the values in the Request.Form object in a filter before the action executes.

hoping there is a built in facility that already can handle this situation automatically.

Thanks in advance for any help

---

UPDATE: setting the culture in the Application_BeginRequest worked! setting it a Filter did not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [set the culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) to `auto` in web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
```

This will use the browser settings to set the proper culture and correctly parse input values based on this settings.

Comment: In my test I am setting the culture and uiculture to fr-FR programmatically in a filter before all actions execute. In my case each user has a profile where they choose which culture to use instead of using the browser setting

Comment: @house9 If the culture is set correctly, model binding should work (i.e. a number formatted according to fr-FR should be mappable to a numerical type when submitted). Are you sure everything's set up correctly?

Comment: I figured this out yesterday was going to post back here - when setting the culture in a filter it did not work, but when I set the culture from Application_BeginRequest it worked perfectly. Guessing the filter is too late in the execution pipeline?